# MVC unit testing - System.NullRefrenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the below code in MVC and trying to write a Unit test - but when running the unit test - gives an error - System.NullRefrenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help

```
namespace Stores.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Home()
        {
          // calling sql queries here 
          return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

****Unit Test :****

```
namespace Stores_UTest
{

    [TestClass]
    public class HomeTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void HomeTest1()
        {

            HomeController h = new HomeController();
            ViewResult v = h.Home() as ViewResult;            
            Assert.AreEqual("Home", v.ViewName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't just call a controller like this.  You need to use Fakes or Mocks to simulate the controller context.  Your are probably getting null ref internally as it is expecting all kinds of context you have not mocked out.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.  Your Home objet references a model object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Erik - the model is defined. this is just a sample and few statements - i wanted to know how to call controller from unit test

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're calling everything correctly. You may want to just test that v is of type ViewResult rather than looking at the name. The quick test that I threw together showed that the name was coming through as an empty string in this scenario rather than "Home."